# The WinRM client received an HTTP server error status (500)

Tags: windows, powershell, networking, winrm

I am are trying to run a Powershell script from one Windows VM and accessing another Windows VM.
But I am getting the following error. I have verified almost all the forums and made essential configurations but no luck. Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this error ?

```
##[error][ABC.domain.com] Connecting to remote server 
ABC.domain.com failed with the following error message : The WinRM 
client received an HTTP server error status (500), but the remote service did 
not include any other information about the cause of the failure. For more 
information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (ABC.domain.com:String) [ 
   ], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMHttpError,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with PowerShell programming. Check out in Server Manager if "WinRM IIS Extensions" are installed. If its already there :

1. Uninstall it and Install it again.

2. Run "WinRM Quickconfig".

Comment: @iRon It is working in rest of the servers even though the WinRM IIS Extensions were not installed in those servers.

Answer (score 0):

This was occurring for us because the WinRm service configuration had a different certificate thumbprint to the https listener's we were configuring.

eg The thumbprints from the following two lines did not match

```
get-childitem wsman:\localhost\listener | ?{ $_.keys -like '*transport=https*' } | get-childitem
get-Item WSMan:\localhost\Service\CertificateThumbprint
```

Setting the service configuration thumbprint to an empty string fixed it for us:

```
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Service\CertificateThumbprint -Value ''
```

For reference, regarding the original errors, in addition to the client's 500 error, the error in the Server's System event logs was as follows:

```
The WinRM service failed to initialize CredSSP. 

 Additional Data 
 The error received was 0x80338082.

 User Action 
 Configure CertificateThumbprint setting under the WinRM configuration for the service. Use the thumbprint of a valid certificate and make sure that Network Service has access to the private key of the certificate.
```